# search api views, sort by most viewed?

Tags: 8, views

I have a view of content.
I have enabled the statistics module and in the view I can add Sort: Statistics: Total Views.

I am now trying to make a similar view page but using search api.

Have enabled search API. and followed these instructions.
https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/modules/search-api/getting-started/search-forms-and-results-pages/searching-with-views/creating-a-search-view

I now have a view which has a search box.

I am trying to add sort by statistics, but it is not an option.

The Search API guide says that it has sorts and filters on indexed fields.
Under /config/search/search-api/index/default/fields I can add remove fields for the index but there is not an option to add the statistics field.

Is there away to get statistics working?
Or would I need to create something like pseudofield which contains the statistics data and then index and sort on that?